# How to represent orientation of rigid body in space with quaternions if roll is zero

Tags: graphics, gis, geospatial

I am trying to represent the orientation of a rigid body, say a pencil in 3 dimensional space with respect to fixed XYZ axes, originating at a fixed origin O. I am trying to visualize arriving at the quaternion representing the orientation of the pencil, by thinking in terms of the axis vector of the pencil's current orientation(i.e axis), and the roll on its own central lengthwise axis,  (Following equation for quaternion from axis-angle representation is from Wikipedia).

[image: Quaternion from Axis angle formula]

Now as per my understanding if the roll of the pencil is zero, then the vector part of the quaternion vanishes, since sin(theta/2) shall become zero, and the resulting quaternion no longer has information of horizontal and vertical tilt with respect to the fixed axes. How I can describe the orientation of the pencil using quaternions in cases where the roll of the pencil is zero.

Comment: What do you mean by orientation? The quaternion does not vanish (because the cosine becomes 1). It represents the complete local coordinate system, which is already oriented.

Comment: By vanish I meant that, I cannot get back the ux, uy, uz, which indicate the orientation of the pencil with the fixed frame  from the quaternion since the sin(theta/2) factor has become zero.

Comment: I am still unsure about what you understand under *orientation*. The ux, uy, and uz components alone are not very expressive.

Comment: The ux, uy, uz do have information about where the pencil is pointing,  but in case there is no roll, then theta being zero, I loose ability to extract ux, uy, uz. Is that a correct understanding, if so how can I deal with such a pencil orientation and still be able to find out where the ux, uy, uz vector is pointing.

Comment: No, these components describe the axis of rotation. They do not describe some principal axis of the coordinate system or any other direction of the system. What you want is probably something like the transformed x-axis: `q x q*`, where `*` is the conjugate operation and `x = i` (or any other principal axis).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Are you indicating I need two seperate quaternions respectively for the pitch and yaw rotations, to represent the orientation of the pencil.

Comment: No, this is how you transform a vector with a quaternion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearer if we imagine that the quaternion specifies the rotation from the default orientation of the pencil to its present orientation. One way of specifying this would be to assume that default orientation of the pencil is along the extrinsic X axis, with the default roll being zero when the label face is on the top. Now one possible way to describe the present orientation of the pencil is by the following three rotations:

1. Rotation about the Z, axis by the yaw angle [image]
2. Rotation about the new Y axis, by the pitch angle [image]
3. Rotation about the new X axis, by the roll [image]

The combination of these three rotations, obtained by their quaternion product [image], will give us the quaternion of the pencil's present orientation, even if the roll, pitch or yaw is zero.